# Line break in QGIS attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I want to add a line break to a long text line in the QGIS attribute table. I made a small excel example to visualize it:

[image]

[image]

Is this possible somehow? I use geopackage as datasource.

Comment: What kind of data source are you using ?

Comment: I use geopackage

Comment: If you insert spaces, the text will automatically break into lines.

Comment: Also try turning on the text edit widget option "multi line" (layer properties > attributes form).

Comment: I have spaces inserted, but the text is not broken into lines. Also activating multiline doesn't work. It just displays the text broken into lines if I click on it in edit mode, instead of displaying it in a single line. If I pull a whole row in the attribute table bigger, the text lines break. But since I have several hundreds of rows this is no option. Any way to automatically choose the line height for every line?

Answer (score 2):

Illustrating a solution to have multiple lines for the value in text field of attribute table:

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments of my question, this works only if I increase the size of a line manually. The lines are not automatically broken if I open an attribute table and this is what I am looking for.